# jQuery: Function to listen each checkbox in table

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I generate this table:

[image: each checkbox table]

with this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: dataToSearchProfile,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

       if(response.success == "success") {
             $('#rBuscarPerfil tr:gt(0)').remove();
             $.each(response, function (index,record){
                 var row = $("<tr class='"+record.IdPerfil+"'/>");
                 $("<td />").text(record.NomPerfil).appendTo(row);
                 $("<td />").text(record.DesPerfil).appendTo(row);
                 $("<td />").html("<a href='#'>Modificar</a>").appendTo(row);
                 if (record.EdoPerfil == 1) {
                    $("<td />").html("<input class='"+record.IdPerfil+"' type='checkbox' checked/>").appendTo(row);
                    row.css("backgroundColor","#bbf2b5");
                 } else {
                      $("<td />").html("<input class='"+record.IdPerfil+"' type='checkbox' />").appendTo(row);
                      row.css("backgroundColor","#fcbfc4");
                 }
                 row.appendTo("#rBuscarPerfil");
            });
       } else {
             $('#errorSearchProfile').html("No se han encontrado resultados para: <b>"+termSearch+"</b>").css("color","red");
       }
  }

});
```

And when the user check in any checkbox in table, will execute a instruction from change background to row (green if is checked and red if is unchecked) then  will execute another function ajax to update record in database and more.. but what interests me most is knowing how to listen to each checkbox to execute an instruction.

I hope can help me please!

Comment: Use the [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a delegate for `click` on your table `#rBuscarPerfil`. Since you're creating the rows dynamically. Any events you create on the rows themselves (before they are created) won't work.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Y355x/

#### Script

```js
$( '#rBuscarPerfil' ).on( 'click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    $( this ).closest( 'tr' ).toggleClass( 'green' );
});​
```

#### HTML

```html
<table id="rBuscarPerfil">
    <tr class="green"><td>1</td><td><input class="1" type="checkbox" checked/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td><input class="1" type="checkbox"/></td></tr>
    <tr class="green"><td>3</td><td><input class="1" type="checkbox" checked/></td></tr>
</table>​
```

#### CSS

```css
tr {
    background-color: red;
}

.green {
    background-color: green !important;
}​
```

Comment: But... $( this ).closest( 'tr' ).toggleClass( 'green' ); not working inside $.ajax function..

Comment: @SoldierCorp Don't put that function inside your `$.ajax()` function. Put it elsewhere in your code.

Comment: So I have it but after doing the update via ajax function, the color has to change to green or red respectively if checked or not

Comment: @SoldierCorp You'll need to add a class to your `<tr>` (or `<td>` wherever you did your color) when you create it, like I did in the sample.

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete solution which you have required. It will do stuff based on check box current status based on checked on unchecked.

**HTML**

```
<table id="rBuscarPerfil" width="90%">
  <tr>
    <th>
      NOMBRE
    </th>
    <th>
      DESCRIPTION
    </th>
    <th>
      ACTION
    </th>
    <th>
      ACTIVO
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="red">
      Perfil Uno
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      Description Del Perfil Uno
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      <input type="button" value="Modificar"/>
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="red">
      Perfil Dos
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      Description Del Perfil Dos
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      <input type="button" value="Modificar"/>
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="red">
      Perfil20
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      Description Del Perfil20
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      <input type="button" value="Modificar"/>
    </td>
    <td class="red">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table#rBuscarPerfil{
  border:2px solid #ddd;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-size:12px;

}

table#rBuscarPerfil th{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  font-size:14px;

  background-color:#224488;
  color:#ddd;
  padding:5px;
}
table#rBuscarPerfil td{
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:1px;
}
table#rBuscarPerfil td.red{
  background:#f698aa;
}
table#rBuscarPerfil td.green{
  background:#a5f6a8;
}
table#rBuscarPerfil input[type=button]{
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#dcdcdc;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("table#rBuscarPerfil input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("red");
                $(this).addClass("green");

            });
        } else {
            $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("green");
                $(this).addClass("red");
            });
        }

    });
});
```

i have created bins for above issue on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa6

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add an onclick tag to your checkbox that calls a function?

So that its like:

```
$("<td />").html("<input onclick='javascript:doSomething(this);' class='"+record.IdPerfil+"' type='checkbox' checked/>").appendTo(row);
```

and then have a function

```
function doSomething(checkbox) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('change','#rBuscarPerfil input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
//your stuff
});
```